# TypeError: messagesRef.child is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a project in React where I'm trying to structure my database using Firebase. I want to create a reference for a child node, but I keep getting

> 'TypeError: messagesRef.child is not a function'

and the code errors out on line 3. Below is my code for the references:

```
/* Create reference to messages in Firebase Database */
var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('messages').limitToLast(30);
var usersRef = messagesRef.child('messsages/users');

usersRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
    /* Update React state when message is added at Firebase Database */
    let message = {
        text: snapshot.val(),
        id: snapshot.key
    };
    var messagesArray = this.state.messages;
    messagesArray.push(message)
    this.setState({
        messages: messagesArray
    });
    let username = {
        text: snapshot.val(),
        id: snapshot.key
    };

})
```

Am I making these references correctly? I followed the Firebase documentation to a tee and I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is that

`var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('messages').limitToLast(30);`

is of type

`firebase.database.Query`

and not of type

`firebase.database.Reference`

The method `child` can only be called on `Reference` type objects, so instead you could use

`var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('messages/users').limitToLast(30);`

This is assuming your database structure is like this:

```
{
    messages: {
        users: {
            someuserid: data,
            otheruserid: data,
            ...
        }
    }
}
```